# (PHP) IF-ELSE two conditions at once

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm new to PHP, now I have some problems in IF-ELSE conditions

These are my codes so far.

```
<?php
include('DBconnect.php');
mysql_query("USE onlinerecruitment");

$app_id_check = "";
$app_pos_check = "";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applicant_skill ");

?>

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>

<th>Applicant's Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Position Selected</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>

</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$check_app_id = $row['App_Data_ID'];
$check_pos_id = $row['Position_ID'];

if($app_id_check != $check_app_id  && $app_pos_check != $check_pos_id){

            $skill_id = $row['Skill_ID'];
            $app_id = $row['App_Data_ID'];

            $result01 =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM required_skills WHERE Skill_ID = '".$skill_id."' ");
            $row01 = mysql_fetch_array($result01, MYSQL_ASSOC);

            $skill_name = $row01['Skill_Name'];
            $pos_id = $row01['Position_ID'];

            $result02 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."' ");
            $row02 = mysql_fetch_array($result02, MYSQL_ASSOC);


            $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application_data_file WHERE App_Data_ID = '".$app_id."' ");
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);

            $app_mail = $row1['App_Email'];

            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applicant_acct WHERE App_Email = '".$app_mail."' ");
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC);



        echo "<TR>";

        echo "<TD>".$row2['App_Name']."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>".$row2['App_LName']."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>".$row02['Position_Name']."</TD>";
        echo "<TD><a href='edit-testing-score-form.php?app_id=".$row['App_Data_ID']."&pos_id=".$row['Position_ID']."'>Edit Testing Score</a></TD>";
        echo "<TD><a onclick='javascript:confirmationDelete($(this));return false;' href='delete-testing-score.php?app_id=".$row['App_Data_ID']."&pos_id=".$row['Position_ID']."'>Delete</a></TD>";


        echo "</TR>";

        $app_id_check = $app_id;
        $app_pos_check = $pos_id;

    }

}

?>
</table>
```

This is my result so far

[image]

And this is my data in the database

[image]

According to my image of my database, the result should not be 2 rows in the table like in the first table. It now prints out only App_Data_ID 00001 and 00012 only which because they are first one who has not the same Position_ID.

My intended result, the table should print App_Data_ID 00001,00002,00012,00013,00014 and so on. It should not print when only App_Data_ID and Position_ID are exactly the same as the last one.

I think my logic in IF-ELSE condition is some kind wrong but I don't know why, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing. 
Change the SQL from `SELECT * FROM applicant_skill` to `SELECT * FROM applicant_skill where App_Data_ID<>Position_ID`. By this you no need to check with if else. It will only display those data where App_Data_ID and Position_ID are not same.
 I thing this will solve your problem.

Comment: sorry "It should not print when only App_Data_ID and Position_ID are exactly the same" this part I fall something, The modified one -> "It should not print when only App_Data_ID and Position_ID are exactly the same as the last one."

Comment: for example, if the first one has App_Data_ID = 00001, Position_ID = 00001 and next one also has the same thing, it will not be printed. but if the first one has App_Data_ID = 00001, Position_ID = 00001 and next one has App_Data_ID = 00002, Position_ID = 00001 it will be printed.

Comment: well i got the solution, just change "&&" to "||". thank you for sharing your answer !!!